# Extract all the pages of all the PDFs present in folder in jpg format and store the images in separate folder

Tags: python, pypdf

I want to get the pdf pages as jpg , (suppose pdf contains 3 pages then output should be 3 images with JPG extension)

I tried 2-3 different ways but not getting the results!
Below is the script I wrote but it only gives the picture of heading present on first page , and also the image created is not stored at the specific folder

```
`import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader
from wand.image import Image as WImage

pdf_file = r"C:\Users\saura\Aidetic\image_processing_data\sample_file.pdf"

def pdf_to_img(pdf_file):
    # Open the PDF file
    # pdf = open("pdf_file", "rb")
    pdf = PdfReader(pdf_file)

    # Create a folder to store the images
    folder_name = pdf_file[:-4]
    if not os.path.exists(folder_name):
        os.makedirs(folder_name)
    page = pdf.pages[0]
    count = 0
    # Iterate through each page of the PDF
    # for i in pdf.pages:
    # Get the current page
    for image in page.images:
        # page = pdf.pages[i]
        # Convert the page to an image
        with open(str(count) + image.name, "wb") as fp:
            fp.write(image.data)
            count += 1
        # Save the image to the folder
        # img.save(filename=os.path.join(folder_name, str(i) + ".jpg"))


# Get the list of PDF files in the current directory
pdf_files = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith(".pdf")]

# Iterate through each PDF file
for pdf_file in pdf_files:
    pdf_to_img(pdf_file)
`
```

Comment: save each page as a single-page pdf, read each new pdf as binary, use an external library to convert it to an image

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, PyPDF2 is not capable of rendering a page of a document as an image.

In contrast, PyMuPDF can do this. Snippet here:

```py
import fitz  # import PyMuPDF
doc = fitz.open("your.pdf")

# NOTE: apart from PDF, you can do the exact same thing for EPUB,
# MOBI, XPS, FB2, CBZ documents - no code change required.

for page in doc:  # iterate over document pages
    pix = page.get_pixmap(dpi=150)  # render full page with desired DPI
    pix.save(f"page-%04i.png" % page.number)  # PNG directly supported

    # if JPEG desired, use a variant that employs Pillow:
    # pix.pil_save(f"page-%04i.jpg" % page.number)
```

1. In next version, JPEG will be directly supported.
2. Method `get_pixmap()` has several parameters to choose the colorspace (e.g. gray), include transparency channel, or restrict the page area to be rendered.

Comment: missing `doc.close()`

Comment: I have many PDFs and I want to save the image say like image_1 , etc, in a folder

Comment: To save in a folder: `pix.save(os.path.join("folder","image_%04i.png" % page.number))`.
`doc.close()` is optional. The `Document` class also supports Python context manager, where closing automatically happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that iterates over a list of files (PDF or other document types), and saves all their pages in a folder "images". This time we are using Python context manager.

```py
import os
import fitz

filelist = []  # list of filenames (PDFs, XPS, EPUB, MOBI, ...)
for fname in filenames:
    basename = os.path.basename(fname)
    first = os.path.splitext(basename)[0]
    with fitz.open(fname) as doc:
        for page in doc:
            pix = page.get_pixmap(dpi=150)
            pix.save(os.path.join("images", "%s_%04.png" % (first, page.number)))
```